# gSoap namespaces from multiple wsdls are all present in request envelope

Tags: soap, wsdl, gsoap

There are N wsdl schemes:

```
a.wsdl
b.wsdl
...
n.wsdl
```

Request (which definition is in a.wsdl) which I sent looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/A/" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/B/" -----> This line is redundant
...
xmlns:nsN="http://www.example.com/N/" -----> This line is redundant
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:A>
...
</ns1:A></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is there any way how to force *gsoap* **NOT** to add all namespaces from all *wsdls* to every requests `SOAP-ENV:Envelope`?

For creating source code I use following commands:

```
wsdl2h.exe -oSoap.h -s -y -c a.wsdl b.wsdl ... n.wsdl
soapcpp2.exe -C -L -n -x -w -c -d.\0 Soap.h
```

as a result I get:

```
soap.nsmap
soapStub.h
soapH.h
soapClient.c
soapC.c
```

Comment: Why not edit the .nsmap file to remove the URIs you don't want?

Comment: @Dr.AlexRE I have 1 .nsmap file, which contains URIs defined in all wsdls, I mean there are URIs connected with request A, and also URIs connected to request B etc. If I remove lets say URIs from request B, because I do not need them in request A, I will break request B.

Comment: No. Look at removing the URIs that are associated with WSDL bindings only, that are not used in messaging. Everything else should stay. Note that extra xmlns bindings are harmless and XML exchanges between machines don't care, so we usually don't bother. Also note that XML canonical messaging removes all unused xmlns bindings, retaining the ones that are used only. You could use XML C14N.

Comment: Separate your client generation per WSDL. You can specify the output file name for each client.